# Count how many rows have a specified value when the value changes with each row

Tags: mysql

When I was querying a table by a specific id I would also count how many rows in that table shared the same name:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE id = 24601
```

Now I'm no longer querying a table by a specific id, instead getting all of the table's output. Is there a way I could still get that count for each row?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(this specific row's name) FROM table
```

Comment: Try using group by

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count of rows per `name`, then use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

You'll get one row per distinct value of `name`, with a second column that has the integer count.

If you also need the other columns for each row, you should write that as a separate query. Don't combine aggregated results with non-aggregated results in the same query.

Comment: I do need the other columns for each row. If the table has 1000 rows, would I need to do 1001 queries? 1 to get the initial output, and then iterate 1000 times to query its output?

Comment: You need two queries. One to get the counts per name, as I showed above. A second query can read the 1000 rows. You don't have to query for one row at a time. One of the most powerful features of SQL is that it treats data as sets of rows.